# @EnableIntegration annotation purpose

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I migrate project from XML Spring Integration configuration to Java DSL. I prepared some integration tests beforehand. So I can do the migration safely step-by-step.

At some point after moving this XML connector definition

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="upstreamAckChannel" />
```

to Java Spring Configuration

```
@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel upstreamAckChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}
```

my integration flow stopped resend test messages to my tests.

After some time and experiments I realized that my Spring Java configuration **must** have `@EnableIntegration` annotation together with usual Spring `@Configuration` annotation for properly work.

The question is what is `@EnableIntegration` annotation semantic? When I can not use it and when I **must** use?

I could find only this small [Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#_configuration) paragraph in official reference manual. Unfortunately, description isn't clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PublishSubscribeChannel class exists inside of the [Spring Integration project](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/PublishSubscribeChannel.html).  The [@EnableIntegration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/config/EnableIntegration.html) annotation is used to adopt a default configuration for Spring Integration, so typically when using Spring Integration you'll want to add it (unless you're using a piece of Spring Integration that doesn't require a context--unlikely).  The only time you might want to forego it is if you want to do your own configuration from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

How can I know what components of Spring Integration are included (or wired) with this annotation? I found some interesting info in [IntegrationRegistrar.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/68c0df5286e9fd762faba628a6efc9252a8a7df2/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/config/IntegrationRegistrar.java) source file in method `registerBeanDefinitions` but I couldn't find exact place where `@EnableIntegration` is really processed.

Comment: I found this as a good answer. Although I agree that we should improve the documentation. Our assumption was about that people are already familiar with something like `@EnableMvc`, `@EnableAsync`, `@EnableRetry`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` and other `@Enable...`. This one for Spring Integration works the same way: it initiates the `IntegrationRegistrar` to register with the ApplicationContext some `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s and other infrastructure. That worked for you before because you had some XML which via its `NamespaceHandler` does the same infrastructure via `IntegrationRegistrar`.